How to set the column span and row span properties of a component which is in a TGridPanel at runtime
I am currently creating a Delphi GUI Application. my form contain at the left a TTreeView were i use a case statement in which every TTreeView Index correspond to one of my panels that i bring to front
What i did remark is that now i made the concept mistake that i need my application to support Both RightToLeft and LeftToRight langauge so given that a lot of my panels are the same i really want to create a single panel at runtime with a panel which containt A TGridPanel that align "altop" with a height of 96px as exemple and another TGridPanel which occupy the rest of the view "minus the TTreeView and the former TGridPanel" so Align proprety would be set to alclient the problem is that my my first TGridPanel which is the altop.
i want it to have one or more child TGridPanel(s) i tried to create my TgridPanel which was succesfull but now the problem is that when i create a TGridPanel as a child of it i can't set the row, column, and rowspan and columnspan propeties where is my mistake?
i have a function that create do the following create a MainGridPanel with 02 rows and 02 columns
after that i create a ChildGridPanel that have MainGridpanel as a container
This is my function to dynamicaly create the Grids (MainGrid and ChildGrid)
function Create_TGridPanel(TGridPanel_Name: string; Parent: TWinControl; Align: TAlign; Height: Integer; Row, RowSpan, Column, ColumnSpan: Integer): TGridPanel;
var
  GridPanel: TGridPanel;
begin
  GridPanel := TGridPanel.Create(Form1); // Correct instantiation
  GridPanel.Parent := Parent;
  GridPanel.Name := TGridPanel_Name;
  GridPanel.Align := Align;
  GridPanel.Height := Height;

  // Ensure there are enough rows and columns
  while GridPanel.RowCollection.Count <= Row + RowSpan - 1 do
    GridPanel.RowCollection.Add; // Add rows until we reach the required row

  while GridPanel.ColumnCollection.Count <= Column + ColumnSpan - 1 do
    GridPanel.ColumnCollection.Add; // Add columns until we reach the required column

  // Set the row and column spans
  GridPanel.RowSpanIndex[Row, RowSpan]; // Set the starting row
  GridPanel.ColumnSpanIndex[Column, ColumnSpan]; // Set the starting column

  Result := GridPanel;
end;

And this is my execution of the code
procedure TForm1.BitBtn281Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Panelyork: TPanel;
  MainGridPanel, FirstChild: TGridPanel;
begin
  // Create the main panel
  Panelyork := Functions.Create_Panel('MainPanel', TabSheet3, alClient);

  // Create the main grid panel with 2 rows and 2 columns
  MainGridPanel := Functions.Create_TGridPanel('MainGridPanel', Panelyork,
    alTop, 128, 0, 2, 0, 2); // Initial parameters for rows and columns

  // Create the first child grid panel, allowing it to span
  FirstChild := Functions.Create_TGridPanel('FirstChild', MainGridPanel, alclient,
    0, 0, 2, 0, 2); // Use alNone to allow spanning
     FirstChild.Align := alclient;
  // Set spans for the child grid panel (this will now be handled in Create_TGridPanel)
  // The spans have already been set in the Create_TGridPanel function
  // so you do not need to add additional rows or columns manually here.
  MainGridPanel.Realign;
end;

i tried to realign my MainGridPanel in the hope that it will refresh the GUI
